# is it possible to access asp.net web application hosted on local machine (not a server, but a normal laptop) via remote pc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, deployment

I have created a

> ASP.NET with c# as back-end code web application, v4.0 framework

Is it possible to host on my local desktop machine and access from remote machine [via internet].
I want to make my desktop machine as server for hosting ASP.NET web apps.

Comment: open port 80 on your firewall? I have a hard time believe you can't google this problem and find 1000 links on how to do this.

Comment: have you tried [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=1038) ?

Comment: there are 4 options to publish
1. web deploy
2. FTP
3. File system
4. FPSE.
I am not sure which one will help me to host on my local machine

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Windows, you can enable IIS and publish your application to that IIS running on your local machine.

If your remote PC is within your network, then you can point your browser to your host PC's IP address or computer name.
If your remote PC is outside your network, you'll need to make sure your firewall allows connections on port 80 (or 443 for https).  You will need either a static IP address, or a service similar to what [dyn.com](http://dyn.com) provides, to point your dynamic IP to a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using MS Deploy  http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy